# Cannot initialize weld

Tags: cdi, weld

I'm using `CDI` in java SE project with `Weld`, so everything was working fine, but now i'm getting the below error when trying to run the code:

```
avr. 07, 2019 4:55:23 PM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup <clinit>
INFO: WELD-000900: 3.0.0 (Final)
avr. 07, 2019 4:55:23 PM org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.DiscoveryStrategyFactory create
INFO: WELD-ENV-000020: Using jandex for bean discovery
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.jandex.AnnotationTarget.asClass()Lorg/jboss/jandex/ClassInfo;
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.jandex.JandexDiscoveryStrategy.buildBeanDefiningAnnotationSet(JandexDiscoveryStrategy.java:116)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.jandex.JandexDiscoveryStrategy.beforeDiscovery(JandexDiscoveryStrategy.java:83)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.AbstractDiscoveryStrategy.performDiscovery(AbstractDiscoveryStrategy.java:109)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld.createDeployment(Weld.java:861)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld.initialize(Weld.java:746)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld.initialize(Weld.java:174)
    at se.Main.main(Main.java:21)
```

here is the Main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FatalException {
        MyBean myBean;

        SeContainerInitializer initializer = SeContainerInitializer.newInstance();
        try (SeContainer container = initializer.initialize()) {//the problem is here

            myBean= container.select(MyBean.class).get();
            System.out.println(myBean.getInfo("0380093"));

        }
    }
}
```

What i'am missing here ! thanks

Comment: Looks like a classpath problem. You may have an older version of Jandex than the one required. Can you post info on how you are setting up the project (e.g. Maven dependencies etc)?

Comment: you are right it was a problem in some dependencies. thanks

Comment: @Hen I have the same error, what was the "problem in some dependencies" please?